# How would a Popup behave on an iPad or Mobile phone?

Tags: user-research, users, usability-study

If I'm using popups or lightboxes for the Desktop version, how would be the behavior when I use it on an iPad or a phone? Also, when I'm interacting with it by using the browser BACK button.

Will this be poor usability or user experience?

Comment: What do you mean by "interacting with it by using the browser back button"? What happens when you use the back button, does it close?

Comment: I was designing & coding our custom modals (I prefer them over lightboxes or similar stuff) for fully responsive website. From my experience, you want to take device **width and height** into consideration (if width is too small, make it 100% wide, same for height). And on mobiles, you really (really) need back button to only close the modal. I added this functionality to our modals after I accidentally navigated away from almost fully filled form in the modal. Once I get home I might turn this into an answer...

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of articles online discouraging the use of modals in mobile screens. However, I think that when implemented correctly, they can be a really porwerful ui tool.

To answer your question, on desktop it should commonly darken the content behind and have it closed by clicking outside or on the close button. The same goes for tablets.

In the case of mobile, I think the best practice would be to make it ALMOST the full width and height of the display (so that it takes up as much space as posible while still making it clear for the user that it is a modal dialog) and coold be closed with the close button or with a gesture. A great example of how this could work is in the mail app for iOS as well as the Now Playing screen on Apple Music.

I leave you this brief article from the iOS Human Interface Guidelines that refers just to that. https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/modality/

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Common modal behavior (light boxes) are pretty consistent when on desktop -> tablet -> mobile.

A modal is an overlay of the current page that you initiated it on. Usually if you hit the back button, it goes to the previous page of what the modal is overlaying. Modals are not deep linked (URL changes) because it implies an overlay.

To get out of the modal there is an (x) which closes it out which brings back visibility on the page that it was overlaid on.

How it is designed will probably vary on what device the user is on:

**Desktop**

You'll probably have the background faded to create focus on the modal itself:

**Tablet**

There could be fairly similar to the Desktop experience, but it depends on the device size itself.

**Mobile**

More than likely a full screen takeover because the space is very limited.

---

You need to be mindful of the device size instead of the device itself. It's all about device size.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps

Comment: Interesting and I agree, but even I as developer hit sometimes the back button to close a modal...maybe a sign of bad ux/ui..

Comment: You might have to ask yourself @Can about the interaction and how it opens. If the animation isn't implying a hover over effect for the modal, then not only is it bad UX, but also bad interaction design.

Comment: Totally agree..lately I watched myself pressing space bar to close a modal like pausing a video^^ and to clarify my first comment this happens only on others apps/websites..